# Trying to remove a hairline on CSS image grid using negative margin

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm afraid this is where my understanding of the box model falls short. If you look at this page on a Mac (doesn't seem to happen on PC) there is a hairline between the images. It's driving my client nuts and wondering if anyone can help me understand how to make these images 100% butt up against each other - so there is no visible line between the images. Hope that makes sense.

http://mkmultimedia.net/labs/mcafee/site/crew.html

Comment: Can you post some images maybe of MAC vs PC since most of us (atleast me) work on one OS at one time!

Comment: This looks suspious - .crew-fade li {margin-bottom: -2px}

Comment: Seems to happen on Firefox PC as well if someone wants to test it

Comment: Since there is no scroll on the page (for me), the last row gets three-quarters of the image cut off in my browser without a way to see the images... not good.

Comment: Thanks Scott!! Set overflow to auto now.

Comment: You must have set it on your test page (perhaps), because the link above still has `overflow: hidden` on the `body` and all your pages get cut off from my viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my CSS reset: The body had `line-height: 1`.
I changed that to zero and got rid of the -2px margins on the LIs.

Comment: This appears to have worked. Don't forget to "accept" your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I, like Andy, was seeing it on Firefox (PC) also (a thin line below some images). I recommend removing the `margin-bottom: -2px` and setting the height of `li` elements in both `.crew-fade` and `.crew` to `height: 110px` (the image height). That seemed to fix it for me.